# error while updating french data

Tags: oracle

there is something wrong in  my update, can anyone help me please ?

this is the orginal update

```
UPDATE TTT
set DESC_FR = 'Autorisation/Résiliation du Prélèvement',
    MENU_FR='Autorisation/Résiliation du Prélèvement'
WHERE REF='RL'
AND APP_NAME='T';
```

when I insert it into the database the words will turn to like this **R?siliation du Pr?l?vement**', so in order to insert the é and è in the database I can use this query

```
select chr(233) from dual
```

Howver, How to write it in a query ? this my way but its incorrect, can you fix it please.

```
UPDATE TTT
set DESC_FR = 'Autorisation/R'||
        select chr(233) from dual ||
        'siliation du Prélèvement',
    MENu_FR='Autorisation/R||
        select chr(233) from dual ||
        siliation du Prélèvement'
WHERE REF='RL'
AND APP_NAME='T';
```

Comment: Check the database encoding. It should be in UTF-8 but it can be in ISO8859-1 by default. `SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`. Check column `NLS_CHARACTERSET`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle its utf8 , but my problem why my update query isnt working ? I tried now 
update ttt set DESC_FR = 'Autorisation/R'|| (select chr(233) from dual) ||'siliation du Prélèvement'... but the result is empty

Comment: Is it a request that you type from SQLDeveloper ou is it a request thrown from the browser? Where do you see the result? SQLDeveloper or web page? The encoding problem occur before the call to the database.

Comment: I see the result from both pl/sql and java application @ArnaudDenoyelle

Comment: have you tried: update ... set desc_fr = 'Autorisation/R'|| chr(233) ||'siliation du Prélèvement' ?  Should work I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by throwing the queries into a notepad , I save it as UTF-8 then I copied it into pl/sql and compiled it. IT seems for U-TF8 database, especially for the special characteres, they should be saved as UTF-8 in the notepad , if they were saved as ANSI, this will cause problem to the database.